# How to pass variables contained in a string to a function in php?

Tags: php

I have 6 arrays and I want to pass only non-empty arrays(at-least 2 arrays are non-empty for sure) to a pre-defined PHP function i.e array_intersect_assoc() so as to get intersection of all non-empty arrays.So I am trying by saving the name of non-empty arrays in a string and then passing the string to the function like this:-

```
    if(!empty($array1) {
        $non_empty='$array1';
    }
    if(!empty($array2) {
        $non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array2';
    }
    if(!empty($array3) {
        $non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array3';
    }
    if(!empty($array4) {
        $non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array4';
    }
    if(!empty($array5) {
        $non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array5';
    }
    if(!empty($array6) {
        $non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array6';
    }
    array_intersect_assoc($non_empty);

    //example $array1:-

    array (size=1)
    0 => 
      array (size=11)
        '_id' => 
          object(MongoId)[24]
            public '$id' => string '577b5248a2b2cb94180017cc' (length=24)
            'id' => string '1065521456869749' (length=16)
            'name' => string 'Ayush Bansal' (length=12)
            'college' => string 'JIIT' (length=4)
            'dob' => string '1995-03-18' (length=10)
            'email' => string 'itsayu01@gmail.com' (length=18)
            'picture' => string 'IMG_20160226_214611_6969.jpg' (length=60) 
            'city' => string 'Noida' (length=5)
            'country' => string 'India' (length=5)
            'time' => float 1447969569
            'lastMilestone' => string 'July 8,2016' (length=11)
```

But its not working.
Please suggest some method to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add them to another array instead a string

Comment: maybe use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of strings

Comment: pro tip: `$non_empty=$non_Empty.",".'$array2';` -> `$non_empty .=",".$array2;`

Comment: Show us some examples of that array. Are they using numeric or string keys?

Comment: Edited.Please see above. @zajonc

Answer (score 1):

Like has been mentioned, add them to an array.

```
array_push($non_empty, $array1);

// instead of
$non_empty='$array1';
```

Otherwise you're just reassigning $non_empty.

Then you can pull them out of $non_empty and use them in array_intersect_assoc().

Comment: its showing at least 2 parameters are required 1 given in array_intersect_assoc() @strange_matter

Answer (score 0):

You can store non empty arrays in array, then use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call `array_intersect_assoc` with subarrays as arguments.

```
$non_empty=[];
if(!empty($array1) )
{
    $non_empty[]=$array1;
}
if(!empty($array2) )
{
    $non_empty[]=$array2;
}
//other checks
$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_assoc', $non_empty);
```

Comment: its showing error array to string conversion. @Arnial

Comment: Update. I loose to closing brackets.

Comment: Still same error. @Arinal

Comment: Did you change $non_empty from string to array? Did you rewrite other checks in same way as in unswer?

Comment: Yes I have changed $non_empty to array and others checks as well.@Arnial